# Asking the number of inputs and use it as a range by python (pysimplegui)

Tags: python, excel, pysimplegui, data-entry

I am attempting to create a data entry form using PySimpleGUI and I want to prompt the user for a number and use that number as the range for inputting data (e.g. if the user enters 30, they can exactly enter 30 inputs).

Here is my code and I would greatly appreciate any suggestions:

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl as xl

# Set theme
sg.theme('Topanga')

# Read in excel file
EXCEL_FILE = 'data_entry.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(EXCEL_FILE)

# Set layout
layout = [
    [sg.Text('Please fill out the following fields : ')],
    [sg.Text('Counter', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key='Counter',default_text = f"{df['Counter'].iloc[-1]} was your last input")],
    [sg.Text('Material', size=(15,1)), sg.Combo(['Cap', 'Crystal', 'pin'], key='Material')],
    [sg.Text('Color', size=(15,1), enable_events = True), sg.Combo(['C', 'G', 'Y', 'B'], key='Color')],
    [sg.Text('Supplier', size=(15, 1)),sg.InputText(key='Supplier')],
    [sg.Text('Shift', size=(15,1)), sg.Combo(['Day', 'Night'], key='Shift')],
    [sg.Text('Time', size=(15, 1)),sg.InputText(key='Time')],
    [sg.Text('Date', size=(15, 1)),sg.InputText(key='Date')],
    [sg.Submit(), sg.Button('Clear'), sg.Exit()],
    [sg.Button('Stop')]
]

window = sg.Window('Data Entry Form', layout)

# Define clear_input function
def clear_input():
    for key in values:
        window[key]('')
    return None

# Begin event loop
while True :
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit' :
        break

    if event == 'Clear':
        clear_input()

    if event == 'Submit' :
        df = df.append(values, ignore_index=True)
        df.to_excel(EXCEL_FILE, index=False)
        sg.popup('Data saved !')
        clear_input()

    if event == 'Stop' :
        path1 = 'data_entry.xlsx'
        path2 = 'data_copy.xlsx'

        wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename = path1)
        ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]

        wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename = path2)
        ws2 = wb2.create_sheet(ws1.title)

        for row in ws1 :
            for cell in row :
                ws2[cell.coordinate].value = cell.value

        wb2.save(path2)

        sg.popup('Data Copied !')

window.close()
```

Comment: Reduce your code to a simple and short script, maybe just an Input element to input and a Button element to start, no `pandas` and `openpyxl`, then what's your expectation about the the 30 Inputs ?